# Angularjs filter search in text

Tags: angularjs

I want filter with angularjs. How to find amen in amenities.
amen = 1;
amenities = "1, 3, 7, 9, 12";

This is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="1" class="pull-left amenities" id="amen-1" ng-checked="false">


amenities = "1, 3, 7, 9, 12";

//amen 1
$( "#amen-1" ).on( "click", function() {
var amen = document.getElementById("amen-1").val();
$scope.amen = amen;
$scope.$apply();
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
    return location.amenities == $scope.amen;
};
});
```

I want search amen in amenities. How do I make a change on this line :

```html
location.amenities == $scope.amen
```

thank you..

EDIT:
Problem solved with @Gonzalo's help:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="more_filter[]" value="1" class="pull-left amenities" ng-click="am_1();" id="map-search-amenities-1">
```

```
$scope.am_1 = function()
{
var kontrol = document.getElementById("map-search-amenities-1").checked;
if (kontrol==true) {
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
return location.amenities.indexOf(1)==0;
};
} else {
$scope.ot_Filter = function (location) {
return location.amenities;
};
}
}
```

Comment: I think I would need to see more complete code in order to properly help you with this example

Comment: "amenities" isn't a array?

Comment: no it is not array

Comment: it should be an array. But if you want to mantain in as string, use indexOf() function, which is vanilla js. Also your code seems a bit incomplete. Is this used in a ng-repeat ?

Comment: I edited my question. when i click amen-1 input (value=1) searc amen-1 in amenities. amenities not array this is text on mysql table.

Comment: you should use ng-click rather than on('click'). You would remove scope.$apply() with that. Where is the desired output shown ? show your complete code, this code has no sense

Comment: gonzalo thank you i tired ng-click and indexOf(amen) working perfectly.

Comment: If you write an answer, I will mark your answer as resolved as indexoff you answer

Comment: @toplumdusmani done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `indexOf()` javascript built in function to search in the string.

```
location.amenities.indexOf(<yoursearch>);
```

another hint:

you should use `ng-click` rather than `on('click')`. You would remove `scope.$apply()` with that